# How to make a condition in SELECT query to filter out only B or not B and A?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a tableA:

```
col1     col2
nameA    A
nameA    B
nameB    A
nameC    B
..........
```

I want to make a condition in this query:

```sql
select *
from tableA
where ....?
```

To return all values that (**only** value B in col2 of name A in col1), or (**no value** A or B in col2 of nameA in col1). Is this possible?

Expected result (for example):

```
col1     col2
nameA    B
```

and

```
col1    col2
```

Comment: you have 2 expected results, which is the correct one ?

Comment: @GuidoG both 2 results in 1 condtition, is that possible?

Comment: You need to explain better what you want, I dont understand what your question is

Comment: @GuidoG I've edited the requirement. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query

```
select *
from   tableA
where  col2 = 'B' and col1 = 'nameA'
union all
select *
from   tableA
where  col2 not in ('B','A')
and    col1 = 'nameA'
```

With out union you can use this

```
select *
from   tableA
where  col1 = 'nameA' 
and (col2='B' or col2!='A')
```

Comment: Can we make those 2 conditions into only 1?

Comment: It is logically not possible. You can either get values that contain 'B' in col2. Or the values the values that does not contain 'A' or 'B' in col2.

Comment: just put `union all` between the 2 queries then. But I agree this does not sounds any logical

Comment: could you explain this bit  (no value A or B in col2 of nameA in col1) clearly? @VũTrần

Comment: @AndrewsBAnthony it means that nameA is not containing any A or B values.

Comment: Use this query @VũTrần

Comment: sorry I accidently had edited your answer in stead of  mine

Comment: @VũTrần check out both the queries. I would suggest to use 2nd query

Comment: Ok, since there are no way to make it in 1 condition so I have to split it up. The reason is that I'm using CASE clause to filter out all the cases. Thank you for your contributions @AndrewsBAnthony

Comment: The without union condition is not correct, since it sitll returns value when nameA is having both A and B. The condition is suppose to trigger when nameA is having only B value, or nameA is not having any A or B values. @AndrewsBAnthony

Comment: @VũTrần check out the changed query. with out union

Answer (score 1):

If both querys from Andrews answer are correct, you can combine them like this

```
select *
from   tableA
where  col2 = 'B' 
and    col1 = 'nameA'

union all

select *
from   tableA
where  col2 not in ('B','A')
and    col1 = 'nameA'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select *
from tableA
where (col1 = 'nameA' and col2 = 'B') 
or (col1= 'nameA' and (col2 is not 'B' and col2 is not 'A'))
```

Comment: This is not correct since when there are both A and B values of nameA, it still giving result back.

Comment: i was changed `and` to `or` but it was wrong, should be `and`, which one was the your query ?

Answer (score 0):

With EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.col2 = 'B'
and exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where col1 = t.col1 and col2 = 'A'
)
```

Comment: Your query only trigger when nameA is having only value B, but it just 1 part of the requirement. The other part is to also to trigger when nameA is not having any A or B value.

Comment: @VũTrần *when nameA is not having any A or B value* then you want no rows returned, right? This is what the code does.